# Is flowing water affected by air resistance?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, projectile

Lets say that water is flowing out of a pipe such that the water does not simply dribble out (basically a fountain). Assuming that the flow of water is very laminar how does air resistance affect the range of the fountain.

Air resistance (by my admittedly juvenile understanding) is majorly caused by the projectile colliding with the air particles in front of it and imparting kinetic energy into them, thus losing speed. However with water fountains the only stuff in front of the water is, well, more water. Therefore the only air resistance that I could think of is the surface to surface friction between the surface of the water spout and the air itself, which I believe is minimal.

Given this, what is the effect of air resistance on water fountains? Equations would be appreciated.

Comment: Try spraying a hose into the wind...

Comment: Yes because that will tell me quantitatively how high the acceleration of drag is against the flow and in what direction, if course, how stupid of me... @honeste_vivere

Comment: You asked "Assuming that the flow of water is very laminar how does air resistance affect the range of the fountain..."  I wasn't trying to be glib.  I was under the impression you weren't sure whether air resistance affected the water flow or not.